# How to add a button to my PHP form that deletes rows from my MYSQL database

Tags: php, html

I am new to php coding.

I am adding each row delete button, but it should not working.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db( "emp",$connection);
if (!$select_db)
{
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM venu ";     
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <table border="2" style= " margin: 0 auto;" id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>rollnumber</th>
          <th>address</th>
          <th>phonenumber</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['rollnumber'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['phonenumber'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td><form action='delete.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden'  value='".$row["address"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='delete' /></form></td></tr>";
                echo "</tr>";

                
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my delete code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db( "emp",$connection);
if (!$select_db)
{
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $rollnumber = $_POST['rollnumber'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    if($name!='' and $id!='')
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'venu' WHERE name='balaji'AND id='93'AND rollnumber='93'AND address='bangalore'AND phonenumber='1234567890'");
    echo "<br/><br/><span>deleted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>ERROR</p>";
}
mysql_close($connection); 
?>
```

I am trying to delete each row using a button, but it is not working.

Comment: `echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a></td>";`

Comment: it is not working getting error

Comment: Tables/columns should be in backticks. You probably don't need all those parameters in the `where` clause, isn't `id` unique? You aren't passing any values to the query.

Comment: Yes, you need to change your delete.php a bit also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your html view page some change `echo "<td><a href='delete.php?did=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";` like bellow:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['rollnumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['phonenumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?did=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

PHP delete code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['did'])) {
    $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['did']);
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM venu WHERE id = '".$delete_id."'");
    if($sql) {
        echo "<br/><br/><span>deleted successfully...!!</span>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}
?>
```

Note : Please avoid `mysql_*` because `mysql_*` has beed removed from
PHP 7. Please use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

More details about of `PDO` connection http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

And more details about of `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Should add a note about SQL injections.

Comment: i have added `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['did']);`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your button like

```
echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a></td>";
```

this will send the ID of the row which you want to delete to the `delete.php`

Secondly you need to change a bit your `delete.php` currently is wide open for [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). Try using [MySQLi or PDO](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) instead

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM venu WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Of course if you need to add more parameters in delete query you should pass them also with the button..

EDIT: Simple example for update record

You can put second button on the table like

```
echo "<td><a href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a></td>";
```

Then when you click on it you will have the ID of the record which you want to update. Then in `update.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE venu SET name = ?, rollnumber = ?, address = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sisi', $name, $rollnumber, $address, $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Here ( in `update.php` ) you can have form which you can fill with new data and pass to variables `$name`, `$rollnumber`, `$address` then post it to update part.

Something to start with: [PHP MySqli Basic usage (select, insert & update)](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage)

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE 'venu' SET name='$name'AND  id='$id'AND rollnumber='$rollnumber'AND address='$address' phonenumber='$phonenumber'"); it is correct

Comment: getting error i want to update total row it is possible

Answer (score -1):

change up your query to use the dynamic value entered by the user, right now it is hard coded in there.

```
session_start();

require_once 'conn.php';

class myClass extends dbconn {
  public function myClassFunction(){

    try {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

          $sql = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = ?";

          $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
          $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
          header("location: ../filepath/index.php");
      }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This line is wrong, you need to set the WHERE clause to the data you get from the hidden input value

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'venu' WHERE name='balaji'AND id='93'AND rollnumber='93'AND address='bangalore'AND phonenumber='1234567890'");
```

Should be:

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'venu' WHERE address='"._POST['address']."'");
```

And in the little form you are using, change:

```
<input type='hidden'  value='".$row["address"]."'/>
```

to:

```
<input type='hidden' name='address' value='".$row["address"]."'/>
```

Comment: `FROM 'venu' WHERE adress` is never going to work, also SQL injections. Also why would you delete on the address and not the `id`?

Comment: Dude, ask that to the OP, im answering his question.

Comment: `adress` is not a column, the form is created incorrectly. Deleting on an address is dangerous as is deleting with `$_POST` directly.